# Java version automatically change to java 1.5 after maven update

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using eclipse as IDE. When I right click on the project and then click maven update my java version change to 1.5. Here is what I did so far, I followed all the steps listed here

http://qussay.com/2013/09/13/solving-dynamic-web-module-3-0-requires-java-1-6-or-newer-in-maven-projects/

1. I changed "Java build path" to "workspace default jre 1.8.0_25"
2. Then changed "java compiler" to 1.8
3. Then changed "project facets">java>1.8
4. Changed pom.xml java version to 1.8

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.1.3.v20140225</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

After all this when I click on "Maven update" my java version change to 1.5 automatically. Also in above steps, first two step's version also change to 1.5 automatically. How can I fix this?

Comment: Mine got fixed using the Project.Properties opening the Java-Build-Path.Libraries tab editing its Modulepath.JRE-System-Library to use the corrected Java version. If I didn't want to change each run configuration for Eclipse.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Open your `pom.xml` file and add the following lines on it:

```
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Where `1.8` is the Java version of your current JDK/JRE. Another way of doing this is adding a `<build>` with the `maven-compile-plugin` as:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version> <!-- or whatever current version -->
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

If you are looking for a way to make it work with Java versions 9+ please take a look at [@JDelorean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49707989/460557).

Comment: I think I already did the second way and I posted the code as well. Don't see what you changed in that code

Comment: Yeah. When I answered you haven't post the code. So, add the first part of my answer. The `properties` tag. If your POM already have a `properties` tag just add the tags inside it, it should work fine.

Comment: @asdlfkjlkj your eclipse is using embeded maven or a external maven installation ? Another question your eclipse is pointing to a JRE or to a JDK ? This is two question regarding eclipse + maven that make all difference.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - I posted a new question. Do u have any idea on that?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855512/java-custom-image-in-joptionpane-showconfirmdialog-is-not-working

Comment: @JorgeCampos where do I find the `maven-complier-plugin` to add the `<build>`? thanks

Comment: @夢のの夢 If you are in a maven project you don't need to find it, just add it to your pom.xml and make sure your computer has internet access. Maven will resolve this as a dependency as well. It will download it and add in your local repository.

Answer (score 34):

Had the same issue when I installed Java 9. My project would default to J2SE-1.5 Execution Environment. Strangely, Java 9 compliance level is not referenced like previous versions, i.e. "1.8", but as "9". So I had to provide my properties and Maven compiler plugin config accordingly:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>9</source>
        <target>9</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This seems to have solved the problem. Works for versions 9 and above.

Comment: Also true for Java 10+ and would like to add that in a multi-module Maven project is only required in the parent POM.

Comment: With Java 9 and above, there is a new `--release <version>` compiler option, which is preferred over source/target. This can be configured with `maven.compiler.release` property or `<release>` setting in maven-compiler plugin. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102787/what-is-the-release-flag-in-the-java-9-compiler

Comment: @ThomasTaylor However, only specifying the `<maven.compiler.release>` property doesn't seem enough for Eclipse. If I write `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` without a source and target, and then run `Update Maven project` in Eclipse, it automatically reverts back to a `J2SE-1.5` container... Is this an Eclipse bug?

Comment: Okay, this is not an Eclipse bug. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=566704#c8

Answer (score 16):

The root-cause of this issue is that if **for any reason** Eclipse's cannot resolve a *valid* value for the `maven.compiler.source` property when generating/updating the .classpath file from the pom, it will simply default to using `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5`.

As expertly answered by [@jorge-campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos), there are multiple ways to set that property.

However, Jorge's answer didn't *appear* to work for me. Here were my settings:

```
<properties>
    <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

...

Exactly. `${java.version}` is *never* going to resolve to the (completely different) property `javaVersion` and Eclipse ignored the property and used the default.

Which brings me back to the "**for any reason**" part I opened with; developer stupidity can be one of those reasons.

Comment: How to change org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5

Comment: Downvoting for saying "developer stupidity can be one of those reasons".

Comment: In my case I am using Maven/Tycho to build Eclipse plugins, and the above default was being ultimately derived from the execution environment specified in the MANIFEST.MF file. Changing the execution environment to JavaSE-1.8 fixed the issue.

Comment: @LukeHutchison - I was referring to my own stupidity, not others - but I appreciate the feedback on the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Add this lines to your pom.xml, then right click your JRE System Library -> Properties -> Set your correct execution environment to Java 1.8 or version you want to set.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version> <!-- or whatever current version -->
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Your answer is missing <build><plugins>...your answer here...</plugins></build> that makes it a clearer answer for people.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter similar issue on one of my team mate machine. He was using old version of Eclipse, I believe it he was using Keppler. Project after being updated change JRE version to 1.5.

Simple updating Eclipse to latest version solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah, no. I'm running Neon, my workspace settings are all 1.8, but when I import (or update) a Maven project, Eclipse insists on using J2SE-1.5.

Comment: @Antares42 are you able to build from command line without any issues? Which m2e version are you using?

Comment: I can build using the command line (or rather "Run as -> Maven build...") without problems. But as soon as I do "Maven -> Update project" I get the JRE libraries as mentioned and Eclipse fails to build the project. I can still build using Maven though. Once I add a ``maven.compiler.source`` property as mentioned in an answer above, everything works fine. My m2e version is 1.7.1-20161104-1805.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (old JBoss Developer Studio), the issue was the JRE environments did not include 1.8 (only 1.7). When I switched the `maven-compiler-plugin` version to 1.7 and did maven update project, it updated the Eclipse JRE system library to 1.7.
[image]

So the solution is to either get a newer IDE version that includes a built-in JRE environment that is 1.8 or later, or try to install it manually (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204314)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. In my case the <properties> tag & nested tags Jorge Campos mentions above were in the wrong place. If I put them between the <hostversion> and <dependencies> tags in the pom.xml file, then this behaviour stopped.

That can be picked up in Eclipse if validation of these files is switched on.

Comment: can you plz provide a full example of your change?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Java 11.
This is how the complete pom.xml file looks like after adding
`<properties>` and `<plugin>`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.akshay</groupId>
  <artifactId>1000SpringSecurityEg</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>1000SpringSecurityEg Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
    <properties>
        <javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
  
  <build>
    <finalName>1000SpringSecurityEg</finalName>
    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
  </build>
</project>
```

The above code worked for me.
Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

I added these lines in my "pom.xml" file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I allow myself to update that subject with Java 11.

I have installed OpenJDK11 on my computer, and I wanted to use it in an app.

I had trouble because Eclipse would always change my JRE to JavaSE-1.5 when I updated my project with Maven.

I had set everything as you said, but I was always directly selecting in my Java Build Path "java-11-openjdk.x86_64" as one of my Alternante JRE. I fixed my problem by selecting in "Execution environment" JavaSE-10 (but you have to double click on it and then choose as a compatible JRE your OpenJDK11 version) as shown on the picture.
[Execution environment setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5kiC.png)

The project will use Java 11 thanks to that (picture) but you have to write 10 for the java-version in the pom.xml and also set java 10 on the Project Facets.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue installing the eclipse update "JAVA 12" from the market.
It makes my eclipse pass from Kepler to Luna.

After that, i have been able to set 1.8 as standard JDK, fixing the "maven update" problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced with JRE 15.0.1 one must ONLY specify the compiler plugin like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>15</source>
        <target>15</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I also provide the properties like

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

this will again reset to JRE 1.5 on `Maven / Update Project`
!!!

Answer (score -1):

Check in `pom.xml` under properties if there is any tag with this `maven.enforcer.plugin.version`. Delete it and replace that with the below code

```
<javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

under properties tag.

And under build, replace the plugins with the below code:

```
 <build>
    <finalName>1000SpringSecurityEg</finalName>
    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
  </build>
```

This solution resolved my issue.

Answer (score -4):

I changed Eclipse from kepler to neon and then updated my project by with Maven -> Update Project.