# Java - Custom Image in JoptionPane.ShowConfirmDialog is not working

Tags: java, css

When the User enters the password and click on Ok button the password will be encrypted and stored in `JTextArea`. And this is working fine. But I want to add a custom logo in the `showConfirmDialog` and `showMessageDialog` popup. I tried with the below code, but the custom Image (logo) is not displaying in the message popup

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter your password : ");
    box.add(label);
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(24);
    box.add(passwordField);

    final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Test\\Internet.png");
    int button = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, box, "Enter your password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, icon);
    if (button == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        String password = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
        String encryptedPassword;
        if (password != null && !password.equals("")) {
            byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(password.getBytes());
            JTextArea richTextField = new JTextArea(10, 10);
            encryptedPassword = new String(bytesEncoded);
            richTextField.setText(encryptedPassword);
            richTextField.setOpaque(false);
            richTextField.setEditable(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, richTextField);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Password cannot be null. Please enter password to encrypt.");

        }
    }
}<br>
```

I'm passing `ImageIcon` object into the `JoptionPane.showConfirmDialog` as an argument. But when I run this, i don't see any Image displayed in the popup. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
 
**Note : I need a custom Image to be displayed in both the popup's. `showConfirmDialog` and `showMessageDialog`**
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. I just ran it in my environment and it worked fine. Which leads me to believe that your problem is the **path of the image**. I even tested it with a path for a image that wasn't there and the window show without showing any image.

I only changed two things, the path of the image obviously:

```
final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("c:\\temp\\poke-ball-png-13_30x30.png");
```

[image]

This image I got from [Free Icons PNG](http://www.freeiconspng.com/free-images/ball-icon-png-4638)

And the `Base64` class since there is no mention from where you are using it I use the java one:

```
import java.util.Base64;
....
byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(password.getBytes());
```

So be sure that your image `"C:\\Users\\Test\\Internet.png"` **Is really there on the disk at that path**

Comment: It is working fine now after resizing the Image. I added these lines                   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(relativePath);
     Image image = icon.getImage();
     Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(140, 140,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
     icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);

Comment: That's great Aishu.