# How to give permanent jdk path in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-luna

Presently I am working on the migration project so the previous project was built on Java 1.5 but I want to migrate to 1.8 whenever I am changing the JDK path in build path its working fine but whenever I am doing maven update project its automatically taking JDK 1.5 so it's becoming difficult for me to change everytime so, Damian someone provide me the solution how to resolve this issue.Moreover, i am using Eclipse Luna

Comment: Change the maven configuration cause the Maven configuration is the leading one...and not Eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seams that this threat may have some answers to your question

[Java version automatically change to java 1.5 after maven update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509928/java-version-automatically-change-to-java-1-5-after-maven-update)

Comment: ... which qualifies this question as a duplicate and should not be answered again.

Comment: Thank you very mutch. Error resolved