# org.apache.camel.NoSuchLanguageException: No language could be found for: simple

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-camel

I have the following exception:
`org.apache.camel.NoSuchLanguageException: No language could be found for: simple`
when calling `DefaultCamelContext.start();`

In my route I need to use `.recipientList(exchangeProperty("name"))` and that's why I've migrated from **Camel 2.12.0** to **Camel 3.4.0** and now I can't even start the context.

pom.xml relevant dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-base</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-language</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
```

I added *camel-language* just in case.

I know about the module system, I've already tried the *dependencyManagement* block from the tutorial (https://camel.apache.org/releases/release-3.4.0/) and got the same error. So I decided not to include unnecessary jars.

I develop in **Eclipse IDE (version 2021-03)**. Maven automatically choses **J2SE-1.5** system library (however my **default JRE is 1.8**) and I can't change it: after updating maven project it gets back to 1.5.

Here's the full stackTrace with some DEBUG messages:

```
[                          main] ResolverHelper                 DEBUG Lookup Language with name simple in registry. Found: null
[                          main] ResolverHelper                 DEBUG Lookup Language with name simple-language in registry. Found: null
org.apache.camel.NoSuchLanguageException: No language could be found for: simple
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultLanguageResolver.noSpecificLanguageFound(DefaultLanguageResolver.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultLanguageResolver.resolveLanguage(DefaultLanguageResolver.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.resolveLanguage(AbstractCamelContext.java:1730)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartStandardServices(AbstractCamelContext.java:3205)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartStandardServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:297)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.forceLazyInitialization(AbstractCamelContext.java:3148)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2550)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2435)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2452)
    at my.camel.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:16)
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see `camel-core` as one of your dependencies, as documented at the URL you provided.

According to the [documentation on expression languages](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/index.html), the `Simple` language is provided as part of the `camel-core-languages` artifact, which is a compile dependency of `camel-core`.

I would suggest trying the Camel POM for dependency management again, making sure to explicitly include the `camel-core` artifact as a dependency.  If `camel-core` alone doesn't solve your issue, then consider adding `camel-core-languages` as well.

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-bom</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core-languages</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: As for your Maven default Java version issue, see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28509928/9260161

Comment: Thank you, @philip, the `camel-core-languages` dependency worked! And thanks for the Maven update link :)

Comment: You are welcome @OlgaVashchenko!  I'm glad that worked for you.