# Eclipse Galileo is not running over Java 1.8 machine

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse Galileo version with Java 1.8 machine and it's not running.

I also have another newer version which is running well, but I need to use this exact version.

What can I do to fix it?

**EDIT 1:
The Java version is 1.7 and not 1.8**

Attached the message that I got:

[image]

**EDIT 2:
The main reason why I need this exact Eclipse version, it's because that I don't JBoss server in this list:

[image]**

Comment: As I said, I need this exact version.

Comment: versions prior to "Luna" werent designed for Java 8

Comment: Why sdo you need this version in particular ?

Comment: I have some friend which have the same version on machine with Java 1.8 and it's working fine.  What i'm doing wrong?  What is this message saying?

Comment: @Dici  I need it because it comes with JBoss application server adapter

Comment: Really? Galileo and Java 8? I thought Keplar needed a plugin to run it, and older simply couldn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391207/how-do-i-add-execution-environment-1-8-to-eclipse-luna

Comment: Java 8 support started from plugin for Kepler, and was added by default from Luna. You would need to search for some non-standard plugin for Galileo, but questions asking for tools or other resources resources are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Guys. OP's question is not about using Java 8 in Eclipse, but to run Eclipse using Java 8.

Comment: Sorry, the Java version is 1.7 and not 1.8

Comment: If you want to add JBoss to list of server adapters in your new Eclipse you can download it by clicking "Download additional server adapters" on right-top of server selection window. What you will need to download is `JBoss AS`.

Answer (score 3):

I can see you're using Java 7 to run your eclipse. Noted by this line in your configuration:

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
                          ^ this points to JDK 1.7
```

Change it to the place you have installed Java 8. Also, use absolute paths here, avoid using things like `..`.

Comment: `+I` for clear thinking. We all assumed that OP wants to be able to use features from Java 8, while he may simply want to run some old code on Java 8 via Eclipse and his real problem may be in fact incorrect path.

Comment: I fixed my machine to have java 1.8 with also a fix for the Environment Variables, then I tried to start Eclipse and it didn't went well, this time no messages were shown, actually, nothing was happened after I clicked on eclipse.exe

Comment: I read your comment from some minutes ago, and I don't have a magic cristal ball to see what's happening in your computer. There must be a log message or something. Try killing the process first (java, eclipse, whatever), then start Eclipse again. And for the new question regarding JBoss, you just need to install a plugin in your Eclipse to support JBoss. If you have any issue related to adding a JBoss (or whatever) server into Eclipse, put it in a new question.